# Set value in ArrayList into TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, .net-2.0, treenode

I have two ArrayLists named `ProductList` and `ItemList`.

**ProductList** holds two *string[]* arrays.

```
string[0]    string[1]
---------   -----------
ProductID    ProductName
---------   -------------
  A001        Food
  B120        NotFood
```

**ItemList** holds three *string[]* arrays.

```
string[0]   string[1]    string[2]
---------  -----------  -----------
ProductID    ItemID       ItemName
---------  -----------  -----------
  A001       X12332        Rice
  A001       X2133         Pepsi
  A001       X12450        Sardine
  B120       H1LKL         Pen
  B120       JLA122        Printer
```

I want to show these data in a TreeView.

So I wrote the coding as shown below:

```
for(int i = 0; i <ProductList.Count; i++) //loop for every item in ProductList
{
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(((string[])ProductList[i])[1]); //create Parent node using ProductName
    TreeView.Nodes.Add(node); //add node into TreeView
    for(int j = 0; j < ItemList.Count; i++) //loop for every item in ItemList
    {
         if(((string[])ProductList[i])[0] == ((string[])ItemList[j])[0]) //Compare if ProdutID in ProductList same with ProductID in ItemList
         {
             node.Nodes.Add(((string[])ItemList[j])[2]); //Add ItemName from ItemList as Child node for current Parent Node
         }
    }
}
```

Running the above code, I get the following result :

```
+Food
 - Rice
 - Pepsi
 - Sardine
+NotFood
 - Pen
 - Printer
```

**Question:**
How can I get the `ItemID` when user select the Node?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for not answering your question yet, but one importante tip: you should change your ArrayList to List<string[]>. This way you don't need those boxing ((string[])item). Your code will get much cleaner and faster.

Comment: @AndreCalil im using .net 2.0 . do not support List property. btw.thx.

Comment: Please, refer to the List doc at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Now, to the point of your question: TreeNode has two interesting properties, Name and Text. Text is what the user reads, and Name is an arbitrary, well, name. Maybe, when you are adding the items to the TreeView, you could set the ItemID as the Name of the TreeNode.

Comment: if my suggestion helped you with this problem, would you mind voting for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, to the point of your question: TreeNode has two interesting properties, Name and Text. Text is what the user reads, and Name is an arbitrary, well, name. Maybe, when you are adding the items to the TreeView, you could set the ItemID as the Name of the TreeNode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Tag` property to store additional information about the node (in your case it can be to hold the `ID`). Later on node click you should be able to get this info. Here is the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)